# Holonomy of non Kahler Hermitian manifold

Tags: complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds, holonomy

For an Hermitian manifold it is equivalent being Kahler and having holonomy in $U(n)$. I was wondering if someone can show me examples of non-Kahler Hermitian that illustrate what holonomy groups can I get (note that I don't assume the manifold to be irreducible or non-symmetric, so also examples with holonomies different than $SO(2m)$ would be cool).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is hardly a classification, but a [Calabi-Eckmann manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calabi%E2%80%93Eckmann_manifold) is diffeomorphic to a product of odd-dimensional spheres $S^{2k-1} \times S^{2\ell-1}$. Picking an arbitrary Riemannian metric $g_{0}$ and averaging over the complex structure if necessary, i.e., defining
$$
g(v, w) = \tfrac{1}{2}[g(v, w) + g(Jv, Jw)],
$$
gives an Hermitian metric. We can therefore arrange holonomy contained in $SO(2k-2) \times SO(2\ell-2)$ for arbitrary positive integers $k$ and $\ell$. (Taking products naturally gives more possibilities.)

Comment: Thanks! This provides quite a few examples. I see that $S^3 \times S^1$ is a 4 Hermitian manifold with holonomy $SO(2)$. Can there be an $2m$ Hermitian manifold with holonomy $SO(2m)$?

Comment: I haven't checked details carefully, but it looks to me that a generic Hermitian metric on a holomorphic $m$-manifold has holonomy $SO(2m)$. It's enough to arrange there's a small cap of spherical metric, for example.